# Creating a better mouse dragger function

Tags: java, algorithms

*I originally posted this to code review, not knowing incomplete code was off-topic and was pointed to post here. I don't believe this question is a good fit for stack overflow because the code I currently have works, I'm just not happy with it.*

I'm creating a java class to automate simple tasks on my computer. The [java.awt.Robot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html)  class already comes with most functions I need. Its mouseMove function will move the mouse instantly to a point, but since a human doesn't instantly move to a point I created a function that will drag my mouse between two points over a duration of time.

My function is fixed at iterating at 1/30th of a second. I used Velocity = Distance / Time equation to get how much the mouse should move every iteration, and used the Robot mouseMove function to actually move the mouse.

I have two issues with my function:

1. A human doesn't move to a point in a straight line, they usually curve in a positive arc no matter what direction. I'm not sure on how I should to change my algorithm to implement that.
2. I used Thread.sleep(33) to get roughly a 1/30th iteration time for the for loop, and multiplied time by 30 to get the correct amount of iterations. I'm wasting CPU sleeping and would rather not sleep at all but I'm not sure how to calculate time since the loop can go at whatever speed it wants.

   ```
   package com;
   import java.awt.AWTException;
   import java.awt.Point;
   import java.awt.Robot;

   public class Tools {
       private Robot robot;

       public Tools() {
           try {
               robot = new Robot();
           } catch (AWTException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }

       //assumes the for loop will iterate at 30th of a second for an accurate time
       public void drag (Point p1, Point p2, double time) {
           try {
               //t = time * 30 to get correct amount of iterations
               for (long t = (long)(time * 30); t > 0; t--) {
                   p1.x += (p2.x - p1.x) / t;
                   p1.y += (p2.y - p1.y) / t;
                   robot.mouseMove(p1.x, p1.y);
                   //sleep to maintain 1/30th of a second iteration
                   Thread.sleep(33);
               }
           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           } 
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Why does the realism of the mouse movement matter if the goal is simply to automate tasks that involve clicking?

Comment: Is the goal to try to avoid bot detection algorithms, e.g. to automate actions on an online game?

Comment: No, it was originally for test automation of a website. I just think it's an interesting problem now, because I couldn't solve how to correctly arc it.

Comment: For test automation realism is out of topic. But a quadratic Bezier curve should do the job. You probably even could ignore most of the 30 points pers second.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with sleeping in your loop, you're not "wasting" any CPU time that way (contrary to, say, busy waiting, which is much worse). Of course the sleep() statement, due to jitter, can sleep longer than expected, but I expect that to be no more than a minor nuisance. For slightly more precise loop timing, maybe [ros::Rate](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Time#Sleeping_and_Rates) could be an inspiration?

Comment: I looked into the Bezier Curve, and solved both of my problems thank you so much!

Comment: You can check out Fitt's Law about how motar skills workd to move mouse and then use Bezier Curve to do the stimulation